# How to run a self-compiled program in Unix/Linux?

Tags: c, linux

Hi I have the following program. When I compile on the terminal gcc main.c I do get an executable named a.out.  However if I type a.out in the terminal I get the following message: a.out: command not found

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PROMPT "print something"
/*
 * 
 */
int main() {

    printf("CS-xxx Assignment x, xxxxx\n");

    printf(PROMPT);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Comment: This question may be useful for many new developers, but it's title needs to be changed, as it's not really a compilation problem.
maybe 'How to run a program in Unix/Linux after compilation?'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you use a Unix-based system, usually "." is not in the path:
So, try ./a.out

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
./a.out
```

Most Linux systems will not look in the current directory for executables, so you need to tell it to look in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

You might not have "." (current directory) in your PATH environment variable.

Try running "./a.out" or add "." to your PATH.

Comment: But bear in mind that "." is not in the $PATH for security reasons, so unless you really need to - avoid to add it to your $PATH.

Comment: I'm with E Eominique: don't do it. But if you *must*, always put '.' it at the *end* of the search path.

Answer (score 1):

Use

./a.out

You must run program specifying current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just type ./a.out and things should work. The issue is without ./ the shell thinks you are typing in a command.

Comment: He *is* typing in a command. The shell just doesn't find one of that name on `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Must run all the c, c++, shell programs by specifying directory path under unix family. the symbol ./ should specify the current directory.

Examples:
   ./kernel  (kernel elf is in current directory)
   ../kernel (kernel elf is in parent directory of current directory)
   childdir/kernel  (kernel elf is in child directory of current directory)

Answer (score 0):

Use ./a.out now you are able to execute your executable file.
This ./ is basically denotes find in current directory.

I think now you get what you have to do.